Anything on Android like Samsung Sound Assistant that allows you to change the volumes of each app individually while they play simultaneously?
I'm changing phones after 6 years (from Samsung Galaxy S9+ to OnePlus Nord 4) and OneUI has been very convenient, Good Lock and odd. I find it easier to not mind the differences too much, but I have a habit of listening to music and watching videos/listening to audiobooks together, and it's kinda unbearable. I haven't been able to find any alternatives as of yet.
The features I mainly use are:

Individual app volume - allows me to control the volumes of each app individually.

Multi sound - to allow Spotify or YouTube Music to continue playing in the background no matter what I do. For example, whether I start video recording or play a video.

Separate app sound - only use this sometimes when I want to continue playing music on the speaker separately while all the other stuff I do doesn't affect the app playing on the speaker.



Found the solution for 1. individual app volume in Sounds & Vibration in settings. Scroll down a bit and you'll find App-specific volume beneath volume button function.
